# What is the difference between quit() method of RemoteWebDriver and WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, remotewebdriver

What is the difference between quit() method of RemoteWebDriver and WebDriver? The reason for asking this question is due to the below observations:

1. When I initiate concrete versions of WebDriver (eg: FirefoxDriver) and call quit() on it, I see that all the browser windows are closed and the corresponding driver (in my case, gecko driver process) process is killed.
2. However, when I use a RemoteWebDriver which uses a GeckoDriverService to perform the same test activities on a browser and then when I call quit() on the RemoteWebDriver, only the browser windows are closed but the process still runs until I stop the GeckoDriverService.

I searched everywhere in the net but could not find an answer. If someone could clarify this observation, it would be really helpful.

Comment: RemoteWebDriver(also implements WebDriver) is generally used in grid setups or cloud setups like sauce etc. It requires a server to handle multiple requests to nodes. Calling a quit on a browser instance will not shutdown the server as it will have other nodes working. The server will have its own shutdown hook. In the case of FirefoxDriver etc there is no requirement for a server and the browser is controlled directly, so everything gets destroyed with quit.

Comment: @Grasshopper Thanks for you comment. I just started doing more research by looking at the source codes. What I noticed is that the concrete FirefoxDriver instance is also using its own proprietary executable driver server (geckodriver.exe) but it gets shutdown when quit() is called on it. Thats the way the it is implemented. Thus when the server dies, everything associated to it (including browser) dies with it. However, the RemoteWebDriver has only the client in it,which interacts with a remote server and thus when quit is called on it, only the client is closed but not the server(obviously).